# Issues with ignoring docker context using .dockerignore

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, dockerignore

```
 .
├── A
└── B
    ├── .dockerignore
    ├── Dockerfile
    └── run_script.sh
```

My folder structure looks similar to the above tree.  I have a  Dockerfile, and a .dockerignore file.  I use the run-script to build my docker image. In the build, i send the entire context from the root.  So, effectively, the context contains  both the folders A, and B.

The run script contains the following command:

```
docker build docker build  -f  Dockerfile ..
```

In the .dockerignore file, I would like to ignore certain files which are inside the folder A.
In the dockerignore documents,  I can use `*/ or **/` basically to ignore subdirectories, but using them here does not seem to be effective in ignoring the files (As they are located in the parent/root directory)

These below commands do not help

```
 **/A
*/A
```

I tried having the .dockerignore file in the root (i.e root contains the folders A, B and .dockerignore -This works). The ignore file contains:

```
A/
B/
```

So my question is if there is a solution of ignoring files and folders which are present in the build context, but are technically a level above the stored .dockerignore?

Comment: The .dockerignore file should be in the root of the context. When you do that, what are the contents of the ignore file, what are the contents of the directories, which files from there so you want to ignore, and which files are you seeing actually get ignored?

Comment: So, dockerignore placed in the root as stated - ( A, B , .dockerignore). It does work.  I was wondering if there is a solution not to do that.

Comment: I am not quite keen on doing that.  The build context is larger because i would like to import a package from the module A into module B.  Module B contains the API that i would like to containerize. Thus me being sceptical about having multiple ignore statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.dockerignore` file has to be placed in the context directory (in your case the folder that contains both `A` and `B`).

This is specified in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#usage):

> To increase the build’s performance, exclude files and directories by adding a .dockerignore file **to the context directory**.

Also [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#dockerignore-file)

> Before the docker CLI sends the context to the docker daemon, it looks for a file named .dockerignore **in the root directory** of the context.

Comment: I guess there is no way around it.  I would really appreciate the ability to ignore files in the context not only in the subdirectories, but in the parent directory as well.